# How to Convert e.x. 2/3 or 1/2 in input to float in cpp

Tags: c++, string

How to Convert e.x. 2/3 or 1/2 in input to float in cpp

```cpp
string s="2/3";
float x=stod(s);
```

Comment: There are 3rd party libraries that can parse numerical/algebraic expressions in strings. Consider using one of them instead of trying to handle this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```cpp
int a,b;
string s="2/3";
sscanf(s.c_str(), "%d/%d", &a, &b);
float x = float(a)/b;
```

Of course, you have to do some validations around `b` being zero.

Comment: Recommendation: Declare the variables as `float`s, parse as `float`s and remove the cast.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::string::find()` to find the `/` char, and then use `std::string::substr()` to split the string into its numerator and denominator portions.

Then use `std::stod()` to convert each to a number:

```
std::string numerator = s; 
std::string denominator = "1";

auto pos = s.find("/");
if (pos != std::string::npos)
{
    numerator = s.substr(0, pos);
    denominator = s.substr(pos+1);
}

double n, d;
double result = 0;
try
{
    n = std::stod(numerator);
    d = std::stod(denominator);
    if (d != 0)
    {
        result = n / d;
    }
}
catch(std::exception& ex)
{
    // parse error
}
```